# Recursively iterate to validate pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

I am trying to do regex validation on a string to ensure it matches a pattern.

Pattern is `<n>...</n>` however my recursive validation breaks as we go deeper into the recursive tree.

```
var is_valid = true;

function is_string_valid(input_string) {
  var regex_tag_set = /\<([0-9])+\>.*?\<\/\1+\>|\{[a-zA-z0-9\_]*?\}/g;
  var regex_tags = /^(\<[0-9]+\>)|<\/?([0-9]+)>(?!.*<\/?[0-9]+>)/g;
  var regex_tag_single = /\<\/?[0-9]+\>/g;
  console.log("start function");
  console.log(input_string);
  
  var matches = input_string.match(regex_tag_set);
  var matches_count = (matches || []).length;
  console.log(matches)
  console.log(matches_count)

  if (matches_count > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < matches_count; i++) {
      if (is_valid) {
        matches[i] = matches[i].replace(regex_tags, "");
        console.log(matches[i]);
        is_string_valid(matches[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    var final_matches = input_string.match(regex_tag_single);
    var final_count = (final_matches || []).length;
    if (final_count > 0) {
      console.log("Invalid; internal tags do not match <n>...</n> pattern."); //this is not being checked on nests.
      is_valid = false;
    }
    return is_valid;
  }
  return is_valid;
}

var str = "Life <0>is <1>amazingly <2>beau<3>tif</3>ul</2></1></0> and <3>progra<4>mm</4>ing</3> is <4>fun</4>.";
console.log(is_string_valid(str));

var str = "Life <0>is <1>amazi</3>ngly <2>beau<3>tif</3>ul</2></1></0> and <3>progra<4>mm</4>ing</3> is <4>fun</4>.";
console.log(is_string_valid(str));
```

**More Detail:**
I'm creating a custom tag parser in Javascript.

the pattern is `<n>...</n>`.

Examples of strings:

```
//This will be invalid because it doesn't follow patter in the nest.
Life <0>is </1>amazingly beautiful<1></0> and <2>programming</2> is <3>fun</3>.

//This will be invalid because it was an close tag nested.
Life <0>is <1>amazi</3>ngly <2>beau<3>tif</3>ul</2></1></0> and <3>progra<4>mm</4>ing</3> is <4>fun</4>.

//This should be valid
Life <0>is <1>amazingly beautiful</1></0> and <2>programming</2> is <3>fun</3>.

//This should be valid
Life <0>is <1>amazingly <2>beautiful</2></1></0> and <3>programming</3> is <4>fun</4>.

//This should be valid
Life <0>is <1>amazingly <2>beautiful</2></1></0> and <3>progr<4>amming</4></3> is <4>fun</4>.
```

Comment: @ggorlen I added more details; the entire string needs to have `<n>..</n>` tags, they can be nested as deep as the want. But the moment any part of the string doesn't follow the pattern by having an extra open/close tag or having an close tag before it's appropriate open tag. Then the string becomes invalid and i want the function to return true. If the entire string is validate then i want it to return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful technique is to have a regexp `<start-tag> no tags <end-tag>` and eliminate it in a loop until there are no more matches. Then test if what's left contains any tags:

```js
function test(s) {
    let re = /<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\1>/g

    while (true) {
        let s2 = s.replace(re, '');
        if (s2 === s)
            return !/[<>]/.test(s)
        s = s2;
    }
}

//

strs = [
    `Life <0>is </1>amazingly beautiful<1></0> and <2>programming</2> is <3>fun</3>.`,
    `Life <0>is <1>amazi</3>ngly <2>beau<3>tif</3>ul</2></1></0> and <3>progra<4>mm</4>ing</3> is <4>fun</4>.`,
    `Life <0>is <1>amazingly beautiful</1></0> and <2>programming</2> is <3>fun</3>.`,
    `Life <0>is <1>amazingly <2>beautiful</2></1></0> and <3>programming</3> is <4>fun</4>.`,
    `Life <0>is <1>amazingly <2>beautiful</2></1></0> and <3>progr<4>amming</4></3> is <4>fun</4>.`,
]




console.log(...strs.map(test))
```

That said, a stack-based parser would be more readable and robust:

```
let lex = String.raw`
    < (?<start> \w+) >
    |
    </ (?<end> \w+) >
    |
    .
`.replace(/\s+/g, '')

function test2(s) {
    let stack = [];

    for (let m of s.matchAll(lex)) {
        let g = m.groups;

        if (g.start)
            stack.push(g.start)
        else if (g.end && stack.pop() !== g.end)
            return false
    }

    return stack.length === 0
}
```

With two kinds of tags, for example, `<n>` and `{...}`, this is more complicated. You cannot simply OR them together in the 'cleaner' regexp, like

```
 /<(\d+)> [^<>]* <\/\1> | { [^{}]* }/  // wrong!
```

because it would accept improperly nested things:

```
 fail <0> { fail </0> fail }  // accepted??
```

You'll have to do the cleanup in two steps: first, remove everything that doesn't look like markup, second, repeat the cleanup loop, but this time with a 'hollow' regexp  `<begin><end>|<begin2><end2>`

Again, a stack-based option would probably work better, I've adapted it to ES3 (I hope).

```js
function test_cleanup(s) {

    let filter = /(<\/?\d+>)|([{}])|./g

    s = s.replace(filter, function (_, tag, paren) {
        return tag|| paren || '';
    });

    let bracket = /<(\d+)><\/\1>|{}/g

    while (true) {
        let s2 = s.replace(bracket, '');
        if (s2 === s)
            return s.length === 0;
        s = s2;
    }
}

function test_stack(s) {

    let lex = /<(\d+)>|<\/(\d+)>|([{}])|./g;
    let stack = [];
    let valid = true;

    s.replace(lex, function (_, open, close, paren) {
        if (!valid)
            return
        if (open)
            return stack.push(open)
        if (close && stack.pop() !== close)
            return valid = false;
        if (paren === '{')
            return stack.push(paren)
        if (paren === '}' && stack.pop() !== '{')
            return valid = false
    });

    return valid && stack.length === 0;
}


strs = [
    'fail <0> fail </1>',
    'fail { fail {',
    'fail <0> { fail } </0> fail<1>',
    'fail <0> { fail </0> fail }',
    '{ok <0> { ok } </0> ok }',
    'ok <0> { ok <1> ok <2> { ok { ok} ok } </2> ok </1> ok } </0>',
]


console.log(...strs.map(test_cleanup))
console.log(...strs.map(test_stack))
```

Comment: Both are great solutions and a lot simpler than what i was trying to do in my code. Unfortunately i can't use the stack solution since it's ECMA 3 but the first answer your posted works really well. I guess the limiting fact here is my inexperience with regex. I couldn't build one that you did so i tried to approach it from the point of trying to evaluate each result rather than elimination as you suggested. Thank you, this was educational.

Comment: I do have a follow up question if you don't mind. What if you have two patterns? E.g. `<n>...</n>` and `{...}`. Would you just do an or in the regex?

Comment: Why would `(?<!{)<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\1>(?!})|{[\w]*}` be wrong? I took your approached and adapted it to have this sample: https://regex101.com/r/ZYsdyT/1 

This way, 1) `<n>...</n>` is valid, 2) `<n>some text</n>` is valid, 3) `{fieldname}` is valid, 4) `<n>{fieldname}</n>` is valid but 5) `{<n>fsome text</n>}` is invalid. Anything which doesn't have two sets of open/close tags or open/close brackets is invalid. I will try your adapted ES3 stack approach. Thank you so much for taking your time.

Comment: @Jordan: the problem with the first approach in general is how to tell junk from non-junk. With multiple brackets B1, B2, B3... you'll end up with something `B1-open (not B1 and not B2 and not B3) B1-close OR B2-open (not B1 and B2 .... the same thing) B2-close OR.... etc`. With the parser approach, all junk is just `.`